# Document AI - Extracting line instead chunks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I'm trying to extract lines instead of table but I don't know what's the best alternative to achieve that.

**Alternative one**

This try was simply rely on Document AI, but it identifies separated texts by '\n' when it should've be a whole line, for example:

> Eritrocitos\n5,33 \n4,50 a 5,50 \nHemoglobina\n17,2 g \n13

**Alternative two**

The second try would be based on polygons but the Document AI service is returning the content empty

```rb
(ruby) page.lines.first.layout.text_anchor.content
""
```

even if I will be able to get by polygons I would have an empty content.

Curiously this alternative returns error when I access the object page

> #<ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8> rescued during inspection

I don't know if this is causing the content empty. I implemented the quickstart for ruby found [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/samples/documentai-process-ocr-document?hl=en)

**Alternative three**

It would be train a model to identify a whole line

Every tried was based on this PDF file

[image]

At the end of the day, I just want to extract line by line

**EDIT**

@holt, I've been working with python as well trying to understand how I can archive my needs.

I copied and pasted the python code that I found [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/samples/documentai-process-ocr-document?hl=en), I only changed paragraph and line indexes trying to reach the right line and I didn't have a good result.

The output was that, I highlighted the content that I was expecting to see the whole line.

```
Page 1:
Width: 1681.0
Height: 2379.0
Detected languages:
48 blocks detected:
    First text block: 'São Paulo\n'
    Last text block: '自\n'
48 paragraphs detected:
    First paragraph text: 'Ferritina\n' <-----
    Last paragraph text: '自\n'
59 lines detected:
    First line text: '379,1 ng/mL\n' <------
    Last line text: '自\n'
275 tokens detected:
    First token text: 'São '
    First token break type: 'SPACE'
    Last token text: '自\n'
    Last token break type: 'TYPE_UNSPECIFIED'
1266 symbols detected:
    First symbol text: 'S'
    Last symbol text: '自'
Quality score: 95.3%
Detected defects:
    quality/defect_document_cutoff: 100.0%
    quality/defect_glare: 64.8%
    quality/defect_text_cutoff: 50.0%
```

Paragraph and line only returned words (Ferritina and 397,1 ng/mL)

I also ran the test on GCP and it's clear that Document AI is no selecting the whole line, only separate words.

[image]

Is there a way to catch the whole line using this processor?

Answer (score 1):

This page in the documentation describes the structure of the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#text_layout_and_quality_scores) output object.

Each [`Document.page`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#page) contains elements such as [`Paragraph`s](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#paragraph) and [`Line`s](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#line) that contain [`Layout`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#layout) metadata about the page elements. The [`Layout.text_anchor`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#textanchor) field contains [`TextSegment`s](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#textsegment) which are indexes into the [`Document.text`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#FIELDS.text) field.

NOTE: `TextAnchor` has a [`content`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#TextAnchor.FIELDS.content) field which it looks like you are trying to access, however this will only be populated for [`formField`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#formfield) elements, not all of the layout types.

You will need to use the `TextAnchor` as an index into the `Document.text` field to get the original document text of the line. You can refer to the code samples in Python, Java, and Node.JS here to see how this can be done. (There's not a Ruby sample in the documentation for parsing this response, but the logic will work the same way)

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#documentai_process_ocr_document-python

I'm not great at Ruby, but I attempted to translate the Python sample so that you can get started.

```rb
# Include the necessary libraries
require "google/cloud/document_ai"

# Define the function to process the document for OCR
def process_document_ocr_sample(project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version, file_path, mime_type)

  # Online processing request to Document AI
  document = process_document(project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version, file_path, mime_type)

  text = document.text
  puts "Full document text: #{text}\n"
  puts "There are #{document.pages.length} page(s) in this document.\n"

  document.pages.each do |page|
    puts "Page #{page.page_number}:"
    print_lines(page.lines, text)
  end
end

# Define the function to print lines
def print_lines(lines, text)
  puts "    #{lines.length} lines detected:"
  first_line_text = layout_to_text(lines[0].layout, text)
  puts "        First line text: #{first_line_text.inspect}"
  last_line_text = layout_to_text(lines[-1].layout, text)
  puts "        Last line text: #{last_line_text.inspect}"
end

# Define the function to process the document
def process_document(project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version, file_path, mime_type)
  # You must set the `api_endpoint` if you use a location other than "us".
  client = Google::Cloud::DocumentAI.document_processor_service

  # The full resource name of the processor version
  name = client.processor_version_path(
    project: project_id,
    location: location,
    processor: processor_id,
    processor_version: processor_version
  )

  # Read the file into memory
  content = File.binread(file_path)

  # Configure the process request
  request = Google::Cloud::DocumentAI::V1::ProcessRequest.new(
    name: name,
    raw_document: {
      content: content,
      mime_type: mime_type
    }
  )

  result = client.process_document(request)

  # For a full list of `Document` object attributes, reference the documentation
  result.document
end

# Define the function to convert layout to text
def layout_to_text(layout, text)
  segments = layout.text_anchor.text_segments.map do |segment|
    text[segment.start_index.to_i...segment.end_index.to_i]
  end

  segments.join("")
end

# Uncomment and set the appropriate values before running the sample
# project_id = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
# location = "YOUR_PROCESSOR_LOCATION"
# processor_id = "YOUR_PROCESSOR_ID"
# processor_version = "rc"
# file_path = "/path/to/local/pdf"
# mime_type = "application/pdf"

# Run the sample
# process_document_ocr_sample(project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version, file_path, mime_type)
```

If you can use Python, there's also the [Document AI Toolbox Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/toolbox#quickstart) which provides some layers of abstraction to make the response easier to parse.